# Splitting fields isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

I am trying to show the following: 
$\Omega^{X^2-2}_\mathbb{Q} \ncong \Omega^{X^2-3}_{\mathbb{Q}}$, but $\Omega^{X^2-\overline{2}}_K \simeq \Omega^{X^2-\overline{3}}_K$ for $K = \mathbb{F}_5$.

Fort the first part, I have the following: $X^2-2 = (X-\sqrt{2})(X+\sqrt{2})$, and $X^2-3 = (X-\sqrt{3})(X+\sqrt{3})$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \neq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$.

For the second part, $X^2-\overline{2}$ and $X^2-\overline{3}$ are both irreducible in $K$, since they have no roots. That means that the following are their splitting fields:
$$
\mathbb{F}_5[X]/(X^2-\overline{2}), \mathbb{F}_5[X]/(X^2-\overline{3}),
$$
respectively. So I am trying to show that these are isomorphic, but how? Am I on the right track so far? Also, can someone explicitly point out how these two polynomials can be written in linear factors in the above two splitting fields?

Comment: What does $\mathbb Q$ have to do with this question?

Comment: The first two splitting fields are over $\mathbb{Q}$ right?